# Correct use of virtualFolder and physicalFolder

Tags: multitenancy

I am configuring a multiple sites with different languages using virtual folder and physical folder as there is a requirement that specifies to use the same domain to map to different nodes.

These are the site definitions for my sites.

```
        <site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        name="TestSite2"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/fr-BE"
        startItem="/home"
        notFoundItem="/home/Landing Pages/404"            
        loginPage="/loginpage"
        virtualFolder="/fr-BE"
        physicalFolder="/fr-BE"
        requireLogin="false" 
        database="master"
        domain="extranet"
        allowDebug="false"
        cacheHtml="true"
        htmlCacheSize="10MB"
        registryCacheSize="0"
        viewStateCacheSize="0"
        xslCacheSize="5MB"
        filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB"
        language="fr-BE"
        enablePreview="true"
        enableWebEdit="true"
        enableDebugger="false"
        disableClientData="false"
        systemFilesPath="/sitecore/media library/System" 
        robotsTxtItem="/robotstxt File"
        targetHostName="testsite"
        xmlSitemapFilename="sitemap.xml"
        xmlSitemapDisableCompression="true" 
        scheme="http"           
        />


        <site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        name="TestSite3"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/nl-BE"
        startItem="/home"
        notFoundItem="/home/Landing Pages/404"           
        loginPage="/loginpage"
        virtualFolder="/nl-BE"
        physicalFolder="/nl-BE"
        requireLogin="false" 
        database="master"
        domain="extranet"
        allowDebug="false"
        cacheHtml="true"
        htmlCacheSize="10MB"
        registryCacheSize="0"
        viewStateCacheSize="0"
        xslCacheSize="5MB"
        filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB"
        language="nl-BE"
        enablePreview="true"
        enableWebEdit="true"
        enableDebugger="false"
        disableClientData="false"
        systemFilesPath="/sitecore/media library/System" 
        robotsTxtItem="/robotstxt File"
        targetHostName="testsite"
        xmlSitemapFilename="sitemap.xml"
        xmlSitemapDisableCompression="true" 
        scheme="http"           
        />
```

The setting `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage` has been patched to `false`

The issue I am having is that the site context that is being resolved to `website` when opening `http://testsite/fr-be` or `http://testsite/nl-be`.

It is not being resolved to the  `TestSite2` or `TestSite3`.

Is this the default behaviour?

I am using sitecore 8.2 Update 1.

Comment: Try removing `<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.StripLanguage, Sitecore.Kernel" />` from the `<preprocessRequest>` pipeline, see if it makes a difference.

Comment: From what I know that's a problem with Sitecore languages in the url. Sitecore ignores the first url segment if there is a language with a code equal to what's in the url. I guess if you would try with anything that is not a language code as your virtual folder it would work.

Comment: Can you please check your /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx file to see if the above patched site definitions exists there and they are before the "website" site definition ?  

also check "Language.AlwaysStripLanguage" setting in ShowConfig.aspx also set to "false"...  

If above options are correctly done, then please check if your "website" site definition have any hostName attribute defined ? 
if there is no hostName for "website" definition, then please try removing "targetHostName" attribute from your two site definitions and see if it is working.

Comment: @MarekMusielak I think "Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage" setting set to "false" tells sitecore to ignore language checking as the first part of the url.

Comment: @MarkCassidy i removed the processor `<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.StripLanguage, Sitecore.Kernel" />` but it was still resolving the context to website.

Comment: @scFootsteps the `website` site definition did not contain the targetHostName attribute. After removing the targetHostName attribute of the two site definitions, the context is resolving to the proper site. Please put the comment as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you please check your `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` file to see if the above patched site definitions exists there and they are before the "website" site definition ?

Also check `Language.AlwaysStripLanguage` setting in `ShowConfig.aspx` also set to `false`.

If above options are correctly done, then please check if your "website" site definition have any hostName attribute defined ?

If there is no hostName for "website" definition, then please try removing `targetHostName` attribute from your two site definitions and see if it is working.